# Running meteor app as android app

Tags: android, meteor, android-2.2-froyo

I am new to meteor(even to Linux) and have zero experience in web app development. I am trying to run the sample meteor app as an android application, following the tutorial  [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app). I am done with running it as a web app.To run it in android,as per the instructions in the documentation, i have added the command:

```
meteor install-sdk android
```

but it says to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux).
That link says to download android studio and configure(download SDK platform 22). I am already having android studio with SDK platform 22.
The next step is "[Set ANDROID_HOME and add the tools directories to your PATH](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Linux#setting-android_home-and-adding-the-tools-directories-to-your-path)". I cant get what it says. I am totally confused and stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also having this problem.Got any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

What setting ANDROID_HOME means is that you need to set the environment variable ANDROID_HOME how you do this is by first finding out where your android sdk is installed. Then follow these steps

On MacOS/Linux, define the path to wherever you installed your SDK as ANDROID_HOME:

**MacOS**

`$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/android-sdk-macosx`

If you installed Android Studio, the value will need to be

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`

**Linux**

`$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/android-sdk-linux`

For example in my linux mint intallation, I have android sdk in my `/home/myusername/Android/Sdk` then I would define ANDROID_HOME as -

`export ANDROID_HOME=/home/myUsername/Android/Sdk`

remember these commands have to be typed on a terminal

Then add the paths to the platform-tools and tools sub-directories (Same on MacOS/Linux).

```
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

P.S: If you want to find out where the android sdk is installed, since you mention that you have android studio already installed and set up all you have to do to find out where android sdk is installed is

- Open your android studio
- Find the tools menu at the top - hover over android - and click on SDK manager. The manager has a textbox saying Android sdk location: with the path to the location for android sdk

Comment: But after doing all these i got this: "Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
  is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.". I have already installed API22 and set ANDROID_HOME as you said.

Comment: Did you follow the steps i mentioned in the P.S to find where the android sdk is in your computer, also please mention which operating system you are using

Comment: export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH these two lines are to be tried as it is. right? should i change that PATH with my sdk path?

Comment: mention what value you see in the Android sdk location field in your sdk manager and also mention the command you typed to export the new value for ANDROID_HOME

Comment: sdk location = "/home/user/Documents/sdk"                                                           command i typed = export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Documents/sdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92486/discussion-between-bhargav-and-hari-krishnan).